# Combine legends for Plotly object figure - Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to combine legends from multiple scatter plots using Plotly. I'm displaying a normal scattermapbox fine but I want to highlight specific coordinates using a secondary plot. This is achieved by subsetting the original `df` into a new one: `df1`.

Using below, I've subset indexes 1,10,15 from the original df. I want to plot these values as different colors and display that in a corresponding legend. At the moment, it's only showing up as *trace 2*.

I have manually inserted the intended output. Ideally, *trace 1* could also be renamed.

A separate issue is the vertical space between plots. I can't seem to reduce it using `vertical_spacing`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

mapboxtoken = "pk.eyJ1IjoianBhbGV4MTIzIiwiYSI6ImNsN3NsemlieTA0ZGszdnAzNHRzb3k4emkifQ.DOmCc34Bj1t4zG6O5yVzoA"
mapboxstyle = 'mapbox://styles/jpalex123/cl7sp1tou001q14qtcjt5ndhn'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')
site_lat = df.lat
site_lon = df.lon
locations_name = df.text

df = df.rename(columns={"index":"id"})
df['id'] = df.index + 0

index_list = [1,10,15]
df1 = df.loc[df.index[index_list]]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 2, 
    cols = 1, 
    vertical_spacing=0.001,
    subplot_titles = ('S1', 'S2'),
    specs = [[{"type": "table"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header = dict(values = ['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
    cells = dict(values = [[100, 90, 80, 90],
                           [95, 85, 75, 95]]),
    domain = dict(x = [0, 1],
                  y = [0, 0.3]),
                ), row = 1, col = 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
                lat = df['lat'], 
                lon = df['lon'],
                mode = 'markers',
                marker = go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                size = 5,
                color = 'black',
                )), row = 2, col = 1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat = df1['lat'], 
            lon = df1['lon'], 
            marker = go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size = 10,
            color = df1['id'],
            )), row = 2, col = 1
            )

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat = df1['lat'], 
            lon = df1['lon'], 
            text = ['<br> 1st', '<br> 2nd', '<br> 3rd'],
            textfont = {"color":"white","size": 14,"family":"Courier New"},
            mode = "text",
            name = '',
            line = dict(color = '#DB2B39'),
            hoverlabel = dict(namelength = 0),
            ),        
            row = 2, col = 1
            )

fig.update_layout(mapbox1_accesstoken = mapboxtoken,
          height = 1000, width = 1000,
          margin = dict(l = 10, r = 10, t = 40, b = 10),
          mapbox1 = dict(zoom = 3.5,
          style = mapboxstyle,
          center = go.layout.mapbox.Center(lat = np.mean(site_lat),lon = np.mean(site_lon))
          ))

fig.show()
```

intended output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the coordinates you want to highlight in the legend, you cannot set the names in a list all at once, so you loop through this data frame line by line. Prepare a list of legend names and colors you want to highlight, and set the names and colors by index. Before you adjust the spacing of the graph, the current height setting is set higher than the two required heights, so the spacing adjustment is ineffective.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

mapboxtoken = "pk.eyJ1IjoianBhbGV4MTIzIiwiYSI6ImNsN3NsemlieTA0ZGszdnAzNHRzb3k4emkifQ.DOmCc34Bj1t4zG6O5yVzoA"
mapboxstyle = 'mapbox://styles/jpalex123/cl7sp1tou001q14qtcjt5ndhn'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')
site_lat = df.lat
site_lon = df.lon
locations_name = df.text

df = df.rename(columns={"index":"id"})
df['id'] = df.index + 0

index_list = [1,10,15]
df1 = df.loc[df.index[index_list]]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 2, 
    cols = 1, 
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    row_heights=[0.35,0.60],
    subplot_titles = ('S1', 'S2'),
    specs = [[{"type": "table"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header = dict(values = ['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
    cells = dict(values = [[100, 90, 80, 90],
                           [95, 85, 75, 95]]),
    domain = dict(x = [0, 1],
                  y = [0, 0.3]),
                ), row = 1, col = 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
                lat = df['lat'], 
                lon = df['lon'],
                mode = 'markers',
                marker = go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                size = 5,
                color = 'black',
                )), row = 2, col = 1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat = df1['lat'], 
            lon = df1['lon'], 
            marker = go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size = 10,
            color = df1['id'],
            )), row = 2, col = 1
            )
k = 0
for _,row in df1.iterrows():
    name_list = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd']
    color_list = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
                lat = [row['lat']], 
                lon = [row['lon']], 
                text = name_list[k] ,
                textfont = {"color":"white", "size": 14, "family":"Courier New"},
                mode = "markers+text",
        marker = dict(size=30, color=color_list[k]),
                name = name_list[k],
                line = dict(color = '#DB2B39'),
                hoverlabel = dict(namelength = 0),
                ),        
                row = 2, col = 1
                )
    k += 1

fig.update_layout(mapbox1_accesstoken = mapboxtoken,
                  height = 450,
                  width = 1000,
                  margin = dict(l = 10, r = 10, t = 40, b = 10),
                  mapbox1 = dict(zoom = 3.5,
                                 style = mapboxstyle,
                                 center = go.layout.mapbox.Center(lat = np.mean(site_lat),
                                                                  lon = np.mean(site_lon))
          ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Legend works well. But what if I want to change the height of the figure above 450?

Comment: If the table is as it is, the only way to change the size of the map is to change it to, for example, row_heights=[0.1,0.85]. Then you can try to restore the height. This is my guess and you may need to adjust.